# MVC DropdownListFor html helper interferes with JQuery submit when @size specified

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this bizarre issue with MVC's html helper in that when I specify the @size for @Html.DropdownListFor, it prevents the jquery .submit from communicating with the server.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?  Is there an alternative I could use to make the dropdown tall?  Here's the code:

```
           @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateInProgress", "Audit", new AjaxOptions {     
HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "CreateInProgressSuccess" }, new { id = "CreateInProgressMainForm"}))
           {
              <div id="reqTabContentBox" class="formPageContainer">
                  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ConfigDoc.CreateApproveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc)
                  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ConfigDoc.CreateDisapproveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc)
                  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ConfigDoc.CreateSaveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc)
                  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ConfigDoc.CreateAdvanceButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc)

                  @Html.Partial("_CreateAudit")
               </div>
                       @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AuditDoc.AuditTemplateId, new SelectList(Model.AuditDoc.AuditTemplates, "Id", "Name"), new { size = "6", @class = "left" })
              <div id="finalButtons" class="formPageContainer">
                 <input id="AdvanceDirection" name="AuditDoc.AdvanceDirection" type="hidden" value="Forward" />

                  <span class="field-validation-error" id="CreateFormValidation"></span>  
                  <span class="field-validation-success" id="CreateSaveSuccess"></span> 
                  @if(Model.AuditDoc.CurrentStates.StateName == "Active")
                  {
                    <div class="btnContainer">
                       <input type="button" id="SaveCreateInProgress" class="toggleAllSelectors" value="@Model.ConfigDoc.CreateSaveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc" />
                       <input type="button" id="AdvanceCreateInProgress" class="toggleAllSelectors" value="@Model.ConfigDoc.CreateAdvanceButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc" /> 
                    </div>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    <label>@Model.ConfigDoc.AllEnterPrivateCommentLabel.ConfigurableLabelDesc</label> @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.AuditDoc.PrivateComment, 0, 0, false)

                    <div class="btnContainer">
                       <input type="button" id="DisapproveCreateInProgress" class="toggleAllSelectors" value="@Model.ConfigDoc.CreateDisapproveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc" @Model.OwnerApprovalAttribute />
                       <input type="button" id="ApproveCreateInProgress" class="toggleAllSelectors" value="@Model.ConfigDoc.CreateApproveButton.ConfigurableLabelDesc" @Model.OwnerApprovalAttribute />
                    </div>
                  }
               </div>
           }
```

And here's the jquery submit:

```
$("#CreateAuditMainForm").submit();
```

Here's the generated code for the Html dropdownlistfor helper:

```
<select class="left valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AuditTemplateId must be a number." data-val-required="The AuditTemplateId field is required." id="AuditDoc_AuditTemplateId" name="AuditDoc.AuditTemplateId" size="6" style="display: block; "> ... </select>
```

I'd appreciate any help or words of wisdom!

Comment: Any JS errors? Can you post the generated HTML code for the dropdown as well?

Comment: There are no JS errors.  Here's the generated code for the html helper: <select class="left valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AuditTemplateId must be a number." data-val-required="The AuditTemplateId field is required." id="AuditDoc_AuditTemplateId" name="AuditDoc.AuditTemplateId" size="6" style="display: block; ">

Comment: Hm, can't see any problems with that. Regarding the title of your question it *does* work if you don't specify the size attribute, right? In that case could you please expand the HTML code provided so it includes the form and JS code?

Comment: I've included the form.  The button type is "button" and the JS code calls on the .submit jquery to submit the form.  And yes, it works when size is not used.

Comment: Did you find the answer already? The closest you can get to the size attribute is by using "height" in your css. But that will just increase the box vertically. Also, try changing from size to @size in the code. Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be the reason of the problem, but by the HTML provided on the "select" field, it is not being closed. Maybe this is screwing the DOM structure, causing errors to submit the form on jquery. 
Try to edit the html and close the select field and retry the submit to see what happens.

```
<select class="left valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AuditTemplateId must be a number." data-val-required="The AuditTemplateId field is required." id="AuditDoc_AuditTemplateId" name="AuditDoc.AuditTemplateId" size="6" style="display: block; " />
```

Let's see if we can have a lucky guess. :P

Regards.

Comment: I would assume it wasn't closed because there were <options> that TheDude didn't include, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Nick is correct.  It does have a closing </select>, I just didn't include it in the post.